# Exception Reason while reading pdf in jsp

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, itext

I have wrote a jsp servlet to read pdf  using itextpdf , i end up with exception Can someone tell me the reason for exception

**page.jsp**

```
<html>
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@page import="javax.servlet.*"%>
<%@page import="com.itextpdf.text.Image"%>
<%@page import="com.itextpdf.text.Document"%>
<%@page import="com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException"%>
<%@page import="com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader"%>
<%@page import="com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfImportedPage"%>
<%@page import="com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter"%>
<%@page import="com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte"%>
<%
    response.reset();
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
            "inline;filename=Saba_PhBill.pdf");
    File file = new File(
            "D:\\TNWRD_Documents\\Knowladge_Base\\CHAPTER_I.pdf");
    String OUTPUTFILE = "D:\\TNWRD_Documents\\CHAPTER_II.pdf";
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(in);
    Document document = new Document();
    //PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
    //        new FileOutputStream(OUTPUTFILE));
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(OUTPUTFILE);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
    document.open();
    //PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(INPUTFILE);
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
    int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    PdfImportedPage pages;
    // Go through all pages
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        // Only page number 2 will be included
        pages = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
        Image instance = Image.getInstance(pages);
        document.add(instance);
        cb.addTemplate(pages, 0, 0);
        document.addHeader("pdf", "pdf");
    }
    document.close();
%>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you upload your PDF?

Comment: now changed the code i am able to read and write the pdf but the content is not showing in jsp and the above is latest code

Comment: Michaël Demey yes i am able to upload and download but need to display the writing content in jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you won't be able to display a PDF in a browser if you enclose the PDF file between `<html>` and `</html>` tags. That's illegal syntax.

Furthermore, you're writing the PDF to a `FileOutputStream`. That's... very odd. You need to send the PDF bytes to a ServletOutputStream.

This is the most simple Hello World Servlet: [Hello](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=167).
Do you see which OutputStream is used when creating the `PdfWriter` instance? `response.getOutputStream()` is a `ServletOutputStream` instance.

Of course, while this works for most browsers, you'll encounter some problems with some legacy browser versions. That's why there's also this example: [PdfServlet](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=173)

Finally, you're a JSP developer, so you remember from your JSP courses that creating binary files from JSP is always a bad idea. Good developers write a Servlet to create binary documents.